# Should comments asking rhetorical questions criticizing why you would want to do something be flagged as nonconstructive?

Tags: discussion, comments, not-constructive

I recently asked a question that got tons of answers as well as comments.  Among the comments were a few asking why I would want to do what I was trying to do, and saying/implying it was dumb for me to doing it.

They did not address whether it was something that could be done, how to do it, or anything like that, just questioned why I would want to do such a thing (that thing being something required by the design I was given, no reason given).

Should such comments be flagged as non-constructive?

They don't add anything to the question or any answer, are often insulting, and get exapserating when similar comments appear multiple times after I said I don't know why I would want to do such a thing, I have just been directed to do it by specifications given.  In addition, I had already addressed a similar question.

Comment: Why would you want to flag those comments?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Flagged!

Comment: Because they are not constructive, and in many ways, aren't even relevant to what is being asked.

Comment: @cluemein well if they're not constructive, then yeah flag them as "Not constructive."  Seems pretty obvious.  Not really sure what this meta question is about.

Comment: lol, I get it now.  Took the first comment too seriously.  Which is part of the problem sometimes, I think such comments end up distracting from useful content.

Comment: Usually they're an attempt to identify [xy problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and a sign that your question is insufficiently clear. If you can't do better than *"I don't know why I would want to do such a thing"*, then go back to whomever set you the task and clarify. Without that information, solving the underlying issue is impossible and answering your question directly might be actively counterproductive.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I am asking because I have seen such comments appear a lot, and even by typically good users.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can understand that to a degree, but sometimes the question or similar comment appears multiple times.  Sometimes they go on why you shouldn't do something.  Thing is, I can't exactly ask why everything is being done a certain way because some of the original designers don't work for our organization anymore (such as a mathematician who designed algorithms meant to find certain values and patterns, without clarifying the meaning of certain variables or weird syntax usage, its like putting together a puzzle where I need to create some of the piece myself).

Comment: You can flag them as non-constructive. I would not be surprised though if the flag is denied. I've seen many questions that were asking how to do something really inadvisable. Asking why the OP wanted to do this inadvisable thing was the most constructive thing to do. Certainly more constructive than tossing in a pat answer that would let the OP construct a  very nice noose with which to unintentionally hang themselves. A moderator would have to chime in to tell you how such flags actually play out with them.

Comment: Then this isn't really a problem SO is designed to solve, it's too localised to you, and you will have to create those pieces.

Comment: I understand that sometimes there are better ways of doing something, but usually I am very specific on what I want to do for a reason, and depending on my language usage, I try to make clear whether I'm open to alternatives (If I say, "Is there a way", I am open to loopholes or alternative solutions that have similar effects, while if I say "How do I", I am trying to be very specific in what I want to do, already know its possible, and don't really care about whether its adviseable or not.

Comment: For context, here is the question and the comments that got me wondering about this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752036/client-server-java-application-to-send-messages-on-one-port-but-receive-them-on?noredirect=1#comment57303269_34752036

Comment: @cluemein Then say that.  If you don't have a good reason for doing what you want to do, then it's quite plausible that you'll find out that what you want to do really isn't a good idea, and how you *should* go about doing what you want.  Alternatively, you may find out why you should be using that given approach, helping you better understand your own problem.  Either way, the comment has become extremely productive.

Comment: @cluemein `I am very specific on what I want to do for a reason` then why do you have a problem explaining that reason when asked?

Comment: The answer that also questions why I would want to do such a thing but does actually answer my question I found much more constructive than "Why would you want to waste a port!?"

Comment: @Servy you misunderstand.  I am saying there is a reason I am not looking for an alternative/reason not to do something.  Not that there is a known reason for me to actually do something a certain way.

Comment: @Servy This is about to go into philosophy I think about languages lol.  I have a certain way of reading and understanding phrases that doesn't always match others.  I am typically super literal, such as when I didn't understand the first comment to be a joke.

Comment: @cluemein If there's a reason you don't care why you need to do something then explain that reason when asked.

Comment: @cluemein Part of what makes Jon's comment so funny is that it's not *just* a joke.  You should actually be explaining why you think these comments aren't constructive if you feel they should be flagged as not constructive.  It's actually a legitimate critique of your meta question, but just phrased in such a way as to be ironic as well.  If it was *just* a joke it wouldn't be nearly as entertaining.

Comment: @Servy I guess I understand that.  I understand such comments when they are asking for clarification or constructive critique, but the comment I am referring to in this case did not seem like that, in addition to it being a question that had already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think a comment might be not constructive? **Flag it as not constructive.**

Think a comment might be rude or offensive? **Flag it as rude or offensive.**

Think a comment might be obsolete? **Flag it as obsolete.**

Think a comment might be too chatty? **Flag it as too chatty.**

Got another reason you think it should be deleted? **Use a custom flag.**

The **worst** thing that can happen is that your flag will be **declined**, which will let you know that you **shouldn't flag** comments like that.

The **best** thing that can happen is that your flag is marked **helpful**, which will let you know that you **should flag** comments like that.

Comment: Telling people to flag appropriate comments without actually thinking about them because a mod will decline them for being wrong isn't appropriate.  If the comments aren't unconstructive, he shouldn't be flagging them as unconstructive.

Comment: I think this actually makes sense.  If you think the flag applies, use it.  If its declined, you learn from it.

Comment: You think it is constructive, I think it is constructive, someone else may not, yet another may not as well. The judge is the moderator that reviews the flag. @Servy

Comment: @TinyGiant Telling someone to cast a flag that you know is wrong, and that they know is wrong, is just going to get them flag banned.  And of course, this isn't really even an answer to the question.  Saying, "don't even consider whether or not the comment is actually doing something wrong, flag it anyway" is not at all the proper way to use the flagging system.

Comment: I don't *know* that it is wrong, I think that it *may* be wrong. The asker doesn't know whether it is right or wrong, that is why they are asking.  If you're flagging something it's because you think there may be a problem with it. @Servy

Comment: @TinyGiant `The asker doesn't know whether it is right or wrong, that is why they are asking.` And you're not actually answering that question.  This is a non-answer.  He's asking if a given behavior is appropriate and *you're providing no information about it*.

Comment: @Servy this does answer the OP's question "_Should such comments be flagged as non-constructive?_".  This answer basically says flag them as you see them.

Comment: @ryanyuyu No, it's not answering the question.  The question is asking, "is this constructive" and your answer is, "do this if it's not constructive".  You're not at all answering the question of whether or not it's constructive.  It's begging the question.

Comment: Sure I am, I'm letting the user know that they can get a very authoritative answer by flagging the content, then observing the outcome of the flag. Is it a good idea to go searching for comments matching a criteria and flag all of them if you don't know whether they should be flagged or not? Probably not. Is flagging a comment which you think may be inappropriate, then watching for the outcome of the flag a good way to find out if such content should be flagged or not? Probably. Do I know everything? No. Do you? No. Does anyone? No.

Comment: `Should comments asking rhetorical questions criticizing why you would want to do something be flagged as nonconstructive?` That is specifically asking whether it should be flagged as nonconstructive, which I answered. If you think something might be inappropriate, flag it and see.

Comment: As the moderators treat comments as ephemeral and thus tend to delete them, not getting a flag declined is not that useful a measure for the appropriateness of removing the comment.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, it's *not* appropriate to just flag everything and let the mods sort it out.  If someone asks if something is appropriate on meta you shouldn't just refuse to so much as address the issue and say, "flag it regardless".

Comment: @TinyGiant No, you *didn't* answer whether such comments should be flagged as not constructive.  You begged the question and avoided answering it in any way.

Comment: When you flag something, you're saying that you think there might be a problem with it. Moderators will let you know whether you're right or not. I never suggested that anyone should "just flag everything and let the mods sort it out", I suggested that if you think there might be a problem with something, use the most appropriate flag you figure fits. @Servy

Comment: I'm tempted to flag all these comments as not-constructive...

Comment: @Deduplicator So you're saying that moderators don't do their jobs, and that is a reason not to use the flag system?

Comment: @TinyGiant But that's exactly what you did say.  Someone asked if a given behavior is appropriate, and if they should flag it.  You said, "I have no idea, flag it and let a mod decide because I'm incapable of thinking about anything and want a mod to do my thinking for me".

Comment: I said (paraphrased) "if you think it should be flagged, flag it and see if you're right or not". Sure I have an idea, but that is just my opinion. Right now, you're expressing your opinion, and you are free to do so, as am I. In the end, it all depends on the moderator at the end of the flag, and what their opinion is. @Servy

Comment: @TinyGiant: No, that's not what I said. I said comments are treated as ephemeral, mods are not expected to be subject-matter experts, so even if a comment gets removed, that's no assurance that it actually should have been removed, without the mod failing in his job.

Comment: @Deduplicator Why do mods need to be subject matter experts to tell if a comment is constructive or not?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Because that might be neccessary to decide whether it is in any way relevant to the question.

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe but I think in the vast majority of cases they do not.  If you have an example of a non constructive but you need to know the subject matter to know that comment I would love to see it.

Comment: A not constructive flag doesn't say "This comment isn't relevant to the question", it says "This comment isn't constructive". @Deduplicator

Answer (score 13):

It's entirely appropriate, and very frequently extremely helpful, to ask about the larger context of why someone wants to do what they're asking about.  Such comments are entirely appropriate, are not at all unconstructive, and should not be flagged.

If you want to refuse to answer them, that's your right.  You're not *obligated* to answer them, but the users are doing nothing wrong by asking you for more information.

If they're indicating that what you're trying to do is likely to be problematic, or isn't the proper way to solve the problem you have, then that is also *helpful, constructive* behavior, and you should not be flagging comments for informing you about a problem that you have.  If you disagree with their assessment, that's also fine; if you don't want to follow their advice, that is your right, but it's not inappropriate for them to express their concerns.

If a particular comment happens to ask a question or express a concern in a particularly unconstructive way, then you can flag that comment as unconstructive.  The simple act of expressing a concern with your approach is not unconstructive, but there are rare instances where people don't express those concerns constructively.  If you're flagging a comment like this, be sure that you're doing it because they choose to express their concern in an inappropriate manner, and not inherently because they're simply expressing a concern with something that you disagree with.

Comment: I don't think its constructive if the question is asking something that has already been asked and answered though.

Comment: @cluemein That's just not true.  It might mean that you don't find the comment helpful to you, but it doesn't mean it merits deletion.

Comment: So, based on the first sentence of the last paragraph. Subjectively, if you think it isn't constructive you should flag it, if you think it is constructive don't?

Comment: @TinyGiant No.  I'm saying that the behavior that he's asking about, namely expressing concerns with the inherent idea of a question, is entirely appropriate and shouldn't be flagging, but admit that some of these comments will sometimes merit flagging for *entirely separate reasons* than the fact that they're expressing concerns with the approach of the question, and if so, they should be flagged for those entirely unrelated reasons, not because they're pointing out a problem with the question.

Comment: @Servy You seriously think that asking the same rhetorical question over again, when it has been addressed already in dialogue with someone else, is constructive?  So, by that logic, wouldn't duplicates be constructive?  I have no problem per se with questions about the advisability of an action, but when it is asked a second time by someone who clearly has no understanding of what I am even asking, while everyone else does, including someone who already asked something similar and had it addressed, I really don't think that is constructive.

Comment: @cluemein Perhaps they felt that you didn't sufficiently address the point, didn't get the impression that you understood the concern, or the importance of it, etc.  Or perhaps they just didn't understand you.  Someone being *wrong* isn't being *unconstructive*.  It doesn't meant that their content should all just be deleted.  If you think they're wrong then either ignore the comment or explain that you feel you've already addressed the concern.  It's no different than just posting a factually incorrect statement; we don't flag and delete content just because it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just providing this due to some events that occurred regarding this question.  I followed Tiny Giant's suggestion and flagged the comment.  I then returned to my question a few minutes ago, and found that the comment had been deleted.  I think that may be taken as indicating that it was correct to flag it.

Answer (score 1):

If the comment is non-constructive, and only then, you are encouraged to flag it as such.

Is a rhetoric question non-constructive?
Sometimes, often not.

Is a rhetoric question specifically criticizing your approach non-constructive?
Rarely, but it happens.

---

Comments are treated as ephemeral, so not getting your request to delete one declined is not nearly as good a measure of the flag as you might hope for.